# How to store and compare a time and week day periods?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a small app that needs to check wither an event has occured between a particular time of day AND day of week. Users will configure a "Time Period" where they specify a time range (for example 8AM to 5PM) and select certain days of week when that range will be valid (for example Sunday, Monday and Thursday).

Then based on this configuration the app will cycle through all the events and highlight ones that fall within the configured time and selected days of week.

The requirement is quite simple to implement, but I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to do a day of week comparison on each event. I dont want to do 7 if statements (one for each day of week) as there are thousands of events and this seems not very efficient.

Does IOS provide a simpler way? Would binary compare work?

See image of Time Period config mockup to get an idea of what I am talking about.  Whats the most efficient way to store and compare against a configured period such as this??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are these events stored in a database? because if so, you could do a filtering system. before i try to code something up, i would need to know about the database question.

Comment: Assuming you're using NSDate to store your dates, it's trivial to compare two dates.  If you're using CoreData, you can use NSDate as an attribute on your object and write a predicate to search for dates within a range.

Comment: The time period configuration is stored NSKeyArchiver (i.e the NSCoding protocol).
Also the challenge is not comparing two dates. Its checking whether a date fall within a time period. I.e Date/Time 8:50AM Friday, needs to be compared to a time period that is only valid from 8Am to 5pm on Sunday, Monday and Thursday.
The check to see that the "day of week" is within the time period specified means i have to do several if else statements. Looking for a more efficient way. I can think of some but thought i should check if there is a best practice using IOS objects.

Comment: Are you not considering year?